# Vuejs template in IE

Tags: laravel, templates, vue.js

In my blade view, i have code like below:

```
<template v-if="section4">
   <div class="progress-item mt-3">
       <div class="progress-item-top text-align-center">
          <span>TITLE</span>
          @if($routeName === 'planner.home.show')
             <div>
                <a href="{{ route('planner.meeting.index', ['mypage'=>$mypage]) }}" class="btn btn-fill no_print">編集</a>
                <button class="btn btn-fill no_print" onclick="window.print();">印刷</button>
             </div>
          @endif
      </div>
      <div>
          @include('planner.Meeting.mtr4')
      </div> 
  </div>
</template>
```

It works fine in Chrome, but when i test in IE, it show nothing.

I tried to remove condition v-if in template tag and it worked!
So i think that IE has problem with **template v-if="condition"**.
Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: depends which vue builder and what IE, I'm pretty sure that vue-cli3 is deprecating support for IE8 and below

Comment: No, i'm working with IE11

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IE11 doesn't support this tag `<template>`（from HTML5）, you should just change it to `<div>` tag and it will work the same way.